# ClickOnce vs Java WebStart

Tags: java, asp.net, .net, clickonce, java-web-start

I recently created an internal website for my company that launches client side applications. This website is suppose to be the central place from which users will launch all their business applciations. The reason it is a website is because is somewhat difficult to deploy applications to client workstations in our compnay due to packaging requirements, and also we want to make our client thin clients as much as possible. To achieve this what I have currently done is writen a website that laucnhes a ClickOnce application with some arguments passed to it via url. The argument basically provides the command for Process.Start.

As our company is primarily .net I chose ClickOnce however I also know that java webstart can do the same thing. Infact to me it seems to launch a bit faster as well.

Can anyone please provide some pros and cons between ClickOnce and Java webstart?

Answer (score 2):

They are very similar and specular technologies...I think Microsoft has thought to JavaWebStart for ClickOnce tech. But you cannot compare them because ClickOnce is for .NET world while JavaWebStart is only for Java World.

So if your work is primarily based onto .NET, why do you have to evaluate JavaWebStart?

P.S. you know that you can use ClickOnce and JavaWebStart directly from a network share, I suppose...